# .htaccees redirect on long string

Tags: .htaccess

I wan't .htaccees  to check it the url string is longer thnr 155 chars. If it is I want to redirect to an error page.

Her is  a rule that does it (I think) for a 155 long query string, but I can't find a way to  to this for a 155 and longer string. Also I am afraid that works only for url and not query string.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{155,})/?$ 404.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Query string isn't part of match in `RewriteRule` directive. You will need to check `℅{QUERY_STRING}` using `RewriteCond` .

Comment: will this work?

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*\/)([^\/\n]{155,})$ 
RewriteRule error.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to preform the check in index file?

Here is an example:

```
$allowedL = 155;
$path = $SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ( strlen($path) > $allowedL ) die();
```